# Can I call instance function when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 methods, one is internal method and the other one is instance method,
When I'm calling my internal function(`onkeydown="javascript:return checkChatBoxInputKey();"`) it works great,
But when I'm trying to activate the `onclick` event (`onclick="this.CloseChatBox();`) I get the following error:

> 0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support
>   property or method 'CloseChatBox'

Here is my code:

```
function ChatBox(){
    // Methods
    this.CloseChatBox = ChatBox.CloseChatBox;

    // Adding new chat box to page
    $(" <div />").attr("id", "chatbox")
    .html('<div class="chatboxhead">' +                                                    
          '<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Close chat box" onclick="this.CloseChatBox();">X</a>' + // This line fails to work
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="chatboxbody">' +
                            '<textarea onkeydown="javascript:return checkChatBoxInputKey();"></textarea>' +
                    '</div>')
    .appendTo($("body"));

    $("#chatbox_" + this.CallId).show();

    return true;}

function checkChatBoxInputKey(){
    alert("checkChatBoxInputKey");}

ChatBox.CloseChatBox = function (){
    alert("CloseChatBox");}
```

What can I do?

Comment: `$(" <div />").attr("id", "chatbox")`, make sure that you don't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onclick`, `this` is the `<a>` tag itself *not* whatever it was in the `ChatBox` function.

So, you're getting the error because `<a>` tags don't have a `CloseChatBox` method.

I *highly* suggest *not* using attributes for event binding.  Use actual event handlers.  Add a class to the `<a>` tag, then bind an event to it using jQuery.

HTML:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Close chat box" class="closeChatBox">X</a>
```

JavaScript (placed outside of the `ChatBox` function, inside a `$(document).ready`):

```js
$('a.closeChatBox').click(function(){
    ChatBox.CloseChatBox();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so how can I call my function?

Comment: I don't think that will work if there are multiple `ChatBox` instances. In that case, I'd rewrite `ChatBox` as a jQuery plugin.

Comment: @bfavaretto: That's probably a better idea.  I guess you could pass the element to the `CloseChatBox` function also.  `ChatBox.CloseChatBox(this);`